# Create notion dropdown in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Are there any libraries that create dropdowns that look like this?

[image]

I don't care for the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not concerned with the pricing, [KendoReact Dropdowns](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/) have a lot that offers a wide range of professionally designed components that can significantly help. If not, you could combine [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) and any draggable libraries to achieve this. Do check [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable).